# Reload a specific div when gridview row is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview and what I want to do is when I clicked the row get the value of the row I want to reload a specific div. Is there a way I can do this? Please Help. Thank you.

**Here is what I have so far**

```xml
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="graph_val" runat="server"></asp:Label>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

```xml
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel6" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <div class = "prg-dte">
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" class = "srch-res" runat="server" >
      </asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class = "table-grid">
      <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" class = "grd-view table table-hover" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="Gridview1_OnSelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
      </asp:GridView>                                                
    </div>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**This is the div I want to reload**

```xml
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <div id="chartContainer" runat="server" style="height: 150px; width: 100%;">
      </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**This is my onclick function to get the row value**

```vb
Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As HtmlTextWriter)
    For Each r As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        If r.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            r.Attributes("onmouseover") = "this.style.cursor='pointer';"
            r.Attributes("onmouseout") = "this.style.textDecoration='none';"
            r.ToolTip = "Click to select row"
            r.Attributes("onclick") = Me.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" & r.RowIndex, True)
        End If
    Next
    MyBase.Render(writer)
End Sub
```

**This is my javascript to get the pie value**

```
var pie = 0;
function changepie(val) {
    pie = val;

function pageLoad() {
    var grpval = document.getElementById('<%=graph_val.ClientID%>');
    pie = grpval.innerText;
    alert(pie)
}
```

The alert pie is just my way of debugging if I'm getting right value.
I think there's something wrong that I'm doing I actually want to get the gridview row value store it in label and pass in pie chart but I can't make it to work.

```
 window.onload = function () {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
        {

            animationEnabled: true,
            animationDuration: 1300,
            legend: {
                verticalAlign: "bottom",
                horizontalAlign: "center"
            },
            data: [
            {
                indexLabelFontSize: 11,
                indexLabelFontFamily: "Monospace",
                indexLabelFontColor: "darkgrey",
                indexLabelLineColor: "darkgrey",
                indexLabelPlacement: "outside",
                type: "pie",
                background: "#FB404B",


                toolTipContent: "{y} - <strong>#percent%</strong>",
                dataPoints: [
                //{ y: pie, legendText: "" , indexLabel: "PlayStation 3" },
                //{ y: 1, legendText: "" , indexLabel: "PlayStation 3" },

                    { y: pie, name: "Total Load", legendText: "Total Load" },
                    { y: 1, name: "Potential Load", legendText: "Potential Load" },
                ]
            }
            ]
        });
        //alert(pie);
        chart.render();
    }
```

**This is how I get pie chart value from label**

```vb
Protected Sub Gridview1_OnSelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim percent As String = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(6).Text
    graph_val.Text = percent
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.[GetType](), "Script", "changepie(" + graph_val.Text + ");", True)
End Sub
```

Comment: I can't see how you are initializing the pie here. It's all variables.

Comment: Actually Im lost I tried a lot of work around. Don't know now how can I make it to work. :(

Comment: Actually rendering charts is a bit complicated. It also depends on what chart control you are using. Simply passing variables won't make it render.

Comment: Just edited my answer. Include How I render my chart. Please take a look. Thank you! =)

Answer (score 0):

I think an **[UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx)** is what you need.

You must enclose that div inside an UpdatePanel so it can *partially* update/refresh/reload (anything you want to call it) that div only.

Syntax:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<div id="chartContainer" runat="server" style="height: 150px; width: 100%;"></div>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

on Click:

```
Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As HtmlTextWriter)
        For Each r As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            If r.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                r.Attributes("onmouseover") = "this.style.cursor='pointer';"
                r.Attributes("onmouseout") = "this.style.textDecoration='none';"
                r.ToolTip = "Click to select row"
                r.Attributes("onclick") = Me.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView1, "Select$" & r.RowIndex, True)
            End If
        Next
    UpdatePanel1.Update() 'This will update the the contents inside the UpdatePanel
        MyBase.Render(writer)
End Sub
```

Since you mentioned that the div is used as a container for a pie chart, I think you need to call the script after loading its data from your GridView.

Something like:

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "ShowPie", "<script>YourPieScriptInitializer()</script>")
```

Comment: tried it but the pie won't reloading or maybe my problem was with the way pie chart is rendering?

Comment: I think you need to call the script that the pie uses to initialize. Updating the div won't render the pie since most of those controls render with scripts.

Comment: How can I do that? Can you please help me? I'm willing to include how I render my pie.

Comment: Check my updated answer. Just replace the script _YourPieScriptInitializer_ with your function to initialize the pie. Do that code after your loop from your GridView.

Comment: Just saw that you edited your answer. Give me a moment to try it and get back to you to update what happen. Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to include additional details to your posted question. Details like what chart control are you using and what are the functions that control is used to initialize. Something like those. So that we can better help you.

Comment: On my way to edit my question. I'll let you know once I'm done. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround can be:
- add a button (but hidden) in UpdatePanel1 like

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
  <div id="chartContainer" runat="server" style="height: 150px; width: 100%;">
```

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="FunctionToGenerateChart" style = "display:none"/>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Using code-behind:**

```
Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As HtmlTextWriter)
   //Your code
   btnSubmit.Click(null,null);
End Sub
```

**Through javascript**

```
document.getElementById("<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>").click();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Working example: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Auto-Refresh-UpdatePanel-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: I don't know where I went wrong to make it not working.

Answer (score 0):

This can all be done on the client side through jQuery.The example below contains a "Select" hyper link in each row of the GridView.When the hyper link is clicked we execute a jQuery function which gives us acess to every column in the selected row.All we have to do now is take the column value we're interested in and pass it through to the function which creates the chart:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(".select").click(function () {

                var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
                var children = $(tr).children();

                //Find the value of the column you need
                for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
                {
                    var td = children[i];
                    var text = $(td).text().trim();
                    alert(text);
                }
                //Call the chart logic here and pass through the required column value from above...
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a class="select" href="#">Select</a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
```